# Get last value in sequence

Tags: sql, t-sql, teradata

I am trying to return the last value in a sequence of a particular event, my inital thought was to use LAST_VALUE() but I can't get this to work. I could do this with subqueries and joins however is there a window function that would give this result far easier?

Right now the query is pulling the max amount but what I want is the **last** amount based on the seq column

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/af386/2/0)

**Data**

```
| PaymentID |          Description | Result | Seq |
|-----------|----------------------|--------|-----|
|         1 | Entered Payment Page |    Yes |   1 |
|         1 |       Amount Entered |     50 |   2 |
|         1 |       Amount Entered |     60 |   3 |
|         1 |       Amount Entered |     20 |   4 |
|         1 |     Amount Confirmed |    Yes |   5 |
|         2 | Entered Payment Page |    Yes |   1 |
|         2 |       Amount Entered |    100 |   2 |
|         2 |     Amount Confirmed |    Yes |   3 |
|         3 | Entered Payment Page |    Yes |   1 |
|         3 |       Amount Entered |      4 |   2 |
|         3 |     Amount Confirmed |     No |   3 |
|         3 |       Amount Entered |      8 |   4 |
|         3 |     Amount Confirmed |    Yes |   5 |
```

**Current Query Result**

```
| PaymentID | InPayment | Amount | Confirmed |
|-----------|-----------|--------|-----------|
|         1 |       Yes |     60 |       Yes |
|         2 |       Yes |    100 |       Yes |
|         3 |       Yes |      8 |       Yes |
```

**Desired result**

```
| PaymentID | InPayment | Amount | Confirmed |
|-----------|-----------|--------|-----------|
|         1 |       Yes |     20 |       Yes |
|         2 |       Yes |    100 |       Yes |
|         3 |       Yes |      8 |       Yes |
```

Comment: last meaning the highest seq value?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Teradata or SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select paymentid,
       max(case when description = 'Entered Payment Page' then result end) as inpayment,
       max(case when description = 'Amount Entered' then result end) as amount_entered,
       max(case when description = 'Amount Confirmed' then result end) as amount_confirmed
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by paymentid, description order by seq desc) as seqnum
      from paymentinfo t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
group by paymentid;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/af386/19) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: perfect, I did get LAST_VALUE working by using IGNORE NULLS and looking at all rows preceding and following but this seems a lot simpler

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support `ignore nulls` and the question has that tag.